# (Leetcode) Freedom Trail

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, programming-challenge, depth-first-search

I would like to know whether I could make my solution to this challenge shorter and more efficient. Below is the description of the challenge (this is a [Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/freedom-trail/)) -

> *In the video game Fallout 4, the quest "Road to Freedom" requires
>   players to reach a metal dial called the "Freedom Trail Ring", and use
>   the dial to spell a specific keyword in order to open the door.*
>
> *Given a string **ring**, which represents the code engraved on the
>   outer ring and another string **key**, which represents the keyword
>   needs to be spelled. You need to find the **minimum** number of steps
>   in order to spell all the characters in the keyword.*
>
> *Initially, the first character of the **ring** is aligned at the 12:00
>   direction. You need to spell all the characters in the string **key**
>   one by one by rotating the ring clockwise or anticlockwise to make
>   each character of the string **key** aligned at the 12:00 direction
>   and then by pressing the center button.*
>
> *At the stage of rotating the ring to spell the key character
>   **key[i]** -*
>
> - *You can rotate the **ring** clockwise or anticlockwise **one place**, which counts as 1 step. The final purpose of the rotation is
>     to align one of the string **ring's** characters at the 12:00
>     direction, where this character must equal to the character
>     **key[i]**.*
> - *If the character **key[i]** has been aligned at the 12:00 direction, you need to press the center button to spell, which also
>     counts as 1 step. After the pressing, you could begin to spell the
>     next character in the key (next stage), otherwise, you've finished all
>     the spelling.*
>
> ***Example -***
>
> [image]
>
> ```
> Input: ring = "godding", key = "gd"
> Output: 4
>
> # Explanation:
> # For the first key character 'g', since it is already in place, we just need 1 step to spell this character. 
> # For the second key character 'd', we need to rotate the ring "godding" anticlockwise by two steps to make it become "ddinggo".
> # Also, we need 1 more step for spelling.
> # So the final output is 4.
> ```
>
> ***Note -***
>
> - *Length of both **ring** and **key** will be in range `1` to `100`.*
> - *There are only lowercase letters in both strings and might be some duplicate characters in both strings.*
> - *It's guaranteed that string **key** could always be spelled by rotating the string **ring**.*

Here is my solution to this challenge -

```
# Uses dynamic programming

def find_rotate_steps(ring, key):
    """
    :type ring: str
    :type key: str
    :rtype: int
    """
    dp = [[min(i, len(ring) - i) for i in range(len(ring))]]
    dp.extend([[float('inf')] * len(ring) for _ in range(len(key))])
    for i in range(1, len(key) + 1):
        for j in range(len(ring)):
            if ring[j] != key[i - 1]:
                continue
            min_step = float('inf')
            for k in range(len(ring)):
                if dp[i - 1][k] == float('inf'):
                    continue
                step = abs(k - j)
                step = min(step, len(ring) - step) + 1 + dp[i - 1][k]
                min_step = min(min_step, step)
            dp[i][j] = min_step
    return min(dp[-1])
```

Here is the time taken for the example output -

```
# %timeit find_rotate_steps("godding", "gd")

36.2 µs ± 1.33 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Here is my Leetcode result for 302 test cases -

> [image]

**NOTE -** Here is what dynamic programming means (according to [freeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/demystifying-dynamic-programming-3efafb8d4296/)) -

> *Dynamic programming amounts to breaking down an optimization problem
>   into simpler sub-problems and storing the solution to each sub-problem
>   so that each sub-problem is only solved once.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was hard to understand, how your code works, so I started by changing variable names to more meaningful form, also unnecessary `+1`, `-1` operation were fixed (`i - 1`, `1, len(key) + 1`, etc):

```
class Solution:
    def findRotateSteps(self, ring, key):
        cumulative_lens = [[min(i, len(ring) - i) for i in range(len(ring))]]
        cumulative_lens.extend([[float('inf')] * len(ring) for _ in range(len(key))])

        for key_num in range(len(key)):
            for new_ring_pos in range(len(ring)):
                if ring[new_ring_pos] != key[key_num]:
                    continue

                min_sum_len = float('inf')

                for prev_ring_pos in range(len(ring)):
                    prev_ltr_sum_len = cumulative_lens[key_num][prev_ring_pos]              

                    if prev_ltr_sum_len == float('inf'):
                        continue

                    clk_w_len = abs(prev_ring_pos - new_ring_pos)
                    a_clk_len = len(ring) - clk_w_len

                    new_sum_len = min(clk_w_len, a_clk_len) + prev_ltr_sum_len + 1
                    min_sum_len = min(min_sum_len, new_sum_len)

                cumulative_lens[key_num + 1][new_ring_pos] = min_sum_len

        return min(cumulative_lens[-1])
```

Now, it is possible to read the code like a story. The cause of low performance is how you store and search visited letter lens (`cumulative_lens`). You keep them in the list, thus you need to iterate through all items to find **not inf** ones for each key value:

```
for prev_ring_pos in range(len(ring)):
    prev_ltr_sum_len = cumulative_lens[key_num][prev_ring_pos]              

    if prev_ltr_sum_len == float('inf'):
        continue
```

**Example:** you have 100 letters in the ring and 10 letters in the key. You found all possible lengths in the ring (there are 3 only) to the first key's letter and move to the second. It will be good to take just needed **3** in the next key's letter processing, not checking others **97** items, which are 'infs'. It can be done by storing ring letters in  the **dictionary** - the Python's hash table structure, like this:

```
letter_indexes = {
    'a' : [first a's index, second a's index],
    'c' : [first c's index, second c's index, third c's index],
    etc
}
```

In this case, we can get the list of the needed letter positions by doing `letter_indexes[letter]`, not messing with the others. I wrote my own solution, see it in the end.

Also, I did some refactoring of your code:

- changed multiple `len(ring)` calls to the `ln_ring` variable - no performance gain, but more readable.
- changed

  ```
  for key_num in range(len(key)):
      for new_ring_pos in range(len(ring)):
          if ring[new_ring_pos] != key[key_num]:
  ```

  like constructions to more pythonic:

  ```
  for key_num, key_ltr in enumerate(key):
      for new_ring_pos, ring_ltr in enumerate(ring):
          if key_ltr != ring_ltr:
  ```

**Result:**

```
class Solution:
    def findRotateSteps(self, ring, key):
        ln_ring = len(ring)

        cumulative_lens = [[min(i, ln_ring - i) for i in range(ln_ring)]]
        cumulative_lens.extend([[float('inf')] * ln_ring for _ in range(len(key))])

        for key_num, key_ltr in enumerate(key):
            for new_ring_pos, ring_ltr in enumerate(ring):
                if key_ltr != ring_ltr:
                    continue

                min_sum_len = float('inf')

                for prev_ring_pos, prev_ltr_sum_len in enumerate(cumulative_lens[key_num]):

                    if prev_ltr_sum_len == float('inf'):
                        continue

                    clk_w_len = abs(prev_ring_pos - new_ring_pos)
                    a_clk_len = ln_ring - clk_w_len

                    new_sum_len = min(clk_w_len, a_clk_len) + prev_ltr_sum_len + 1
                    min_sum_len = min(min_sum_len, new_sum_len)

                cumulative_lens[key_num + 1][new_ring_pos] = min_sum_len

        return min(cumulative_lens[-1])
```

---

#### My solution:

It works similar to your, but is much faster due to dictionary usage.

```
class Solution:
    def findRotateSteps(self, ring, key):
        # the 'prev_ltr' variable should have the start value in the
        # beginning, so the '#' character is choosed
        # It can be changed to any character different from key's content
        # In other words, it is like '-1' item with 0 index.
        ltr_indexes = {'#' : [0]}

        for idx, ltr in enumerate(ring):
            ltr_indexes.setdefault(ltr, []).append(idx)

        ln = len(ring)
        l_lens = [0] * ln

        prev_ltr = '#'
        for ltr in key:
            for pos in ltr_indexes[ltr]:    
                all_variants = []

                for prev_pos in ltr_indexes[prev_ltr]:  
                    clk_w = abs(prev_pos - pos) 
                    a_clk = ln - clk_w 
                    all_variants.append(min(clk_w, a_clk) + l_lens[prev_pos])

                l_lens[pos] = min(all_variants)

            prev_ltr = ltr

        return min(l_lens[pos] for pos in ltr_indexes[ltr]) + len(key)
```

Comment: Thanks for your amazing solution! It helped me a lot. +1